# Restricting function to unique dates - Multi-Index

Tags: python, dataframe, pandas

I have a list of dates and times in columns of a csv. I'm trying to perform a function on every unique date - for each time associated to that date. The function should start at the first time (930am) of *every* new date. Each of the dates are repeated 42 times. There are 62,035 rows. I say:

My question:  Will a loop like the 'for' loop below logistically achieve that end? I.E., "do something" on each new date for all times in that date *only*. Then move to the next date...

```
data=read_csv(file)  
idf= data.set_index(['date', 'time'])  
for ((date, time), data) in idf:
# (I also tried - for (i in idf):)

 --do something here--
```

Right now, I get the IndexError: 'list index out of range'. 

Any ideas why this might be occuring?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
In [1]: df = pd.DataFrame({'duty': {('11/12/2012', '10:00'): 0, ('12/12/2012', '10:00'): 0, ('12/12/2012', '11:00'): 1}, 'prices': {('11/12/2012', '10:00'): 1, ('12/12/2012', '10:00'): 2, ('12/12/2012', '11:00'): 3}})

In [2]: df.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(df1.index)

In [3]: df
Out[3]: 
                  duty  prices
11/12/2012 10:00     0       1
12/12/2012 10:00     0       2
           11:00     1       3

In [4]: g = df.groupby(level=0)
```

You can do some standard groupby operations, or write your own using [transformation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#transformation) or [aggregation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/groupby.html#aggregation):

```
In [5]: g.sum()
Out[5]: 
            duty  prices
11/12/2012     0       1
12/12/2012     1       5

In [6]: g.transform(lambda x: x - x.mean())
Out[6]: 
                  duty  prices
11/12/2012 10:00   0.0     0.0
12/12/2012 10:00  -0.5    -0.5
           11:00   0.5     0.5

In [7]: g.agg({'prices': np.mean, 'duty': len})
Out[7]: 
            duty  prices
11/12/2012     1     1.0
12/12/2012     2     2.5
```

*There's more examples in [the docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html).*